# Push to several FTP servers

Tags: git, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, sftp

So I have a gitlab repo that currently sync with an SFTP server everytime I make an commit. Now I have another SFTP server which I also have to push the files to but I'm not sure how I should do this automatically. This is the yml script I have right now:

```
stages:
  - push
  - notification

push:
  stage: push
  image: debian:stable
  before_script:
    - apt-get update -y --allow-unauthenticated
    - apt-get install -y git git-ftp --allow-unauthenticated
    
    - git config http.sslVerify "false"
    - git config --global http.sslVerify "false"
    - git config git-ftp.url "sftp://$FTP_URL/$FTP_PATH"
    - git config git-ftp.user "$FTP_USER"
    - git config git-ftp.password "$FTP_PASSWORD"
  script:
   - git ftp push -v --insecure
```

What would the best way to do this to several servers? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the docs at https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/blob/master/man/git-ftp.1.md. You can push directly to an URL:

```
git ftp push -u username2 -p password2 -- "sftp://$FTP_URL2/$FTP_PATH2"
```

You can also try to leverage [scopes](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/blob/master/man/git-ftp.1.md#scopes).

Comment: @jamesberg https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers